# c++ - string subscript out of range - where am I making a mistake?

Tags: c++, string

Where am I making a mistake??

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

string input = "";
string slogovi = "";

int broj = 0;

void main()
{
    printf("Please enter a valid name:\n>");
    getline(cin, input);
    int c = input.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        if (input[i] == 'a' || input[i] == 'e' || input[i] == 'i' || input[i] == 'o' || input[i] == 'u') {
            slogovi[broj] = input[i];
            slogovi[broj + 1] = '-';
            broj += 2;
        }
        else {
            slogovi[broj] = input[i];
            broj++;
        }
    }

    printf("%s", slogovi);
    system("pause");
}
```

The thread 0x14d0 has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The program '[5452] Strings.exe' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).

Comment: Oh forgott that I updated the code, I used c instead (defined that c = input.length();)

Comment: slogvi[broj] is getting a value outside of its current size

Comment: You could have used `string::at()` instead of `[ ]` to detect the error.  Then instead of just a crash, a `std::out_of_range` exception would have been shown, letting you know the error.

Answer (score 2):

The length of `slogovi` stays at `0` the whole time. I understand that you are trying to change it with `slogovi[broj]=input[i]`, but you can't even use the `[]` operator because the length is `0.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? Or, do you need more explanation?

Comment: Totally forgott about that... I should really take a rest. Thanks

Comment: One way to fix this is to just use the append operator += to the string, so you won't go out of bounds, or you could use resize like @MOJNICK points out

Answer (score 2):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at:
"Returns a reference to the character at specified location pos. No bounds checking is performed. If pos > size(), the behavior is undefined."

You could use resize() method, as size of your string is 0.